# SQL How to set a null value to replace another char

Tags: sql, pyspark

I have a table with '#' everytime that there is no information. I would like to replace it by NULL. I know I can go column by column and set a 'case when' condition for each, but I was looking
for a more elegant solution

for example-

| COL A | COL B |
| --- | --- |
| # | ABC |
| 123 | # |

I want to have

| COL A | COL B |
| --- | --- |
| Null | ABC |
| 123 | Null |

Answer (score 0):

In a query, you can use `nullif()`:

```
select nullif(a, '#') as a,
       nullif(b, '#') as b
from t;
```

You can use similar logic in an `update`:

```
update t
    set a = nullif(a, '#'),
        b = nullif(b, '#')
    where '#' in (a, b);
```

Comment: @steven . . . `nullif()` is actually ANSI SQL and is supported by Spark:  https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#nullif and it is supported by all major databases (MS Access being the only database I can think of that does not support it).

Comment: sorry, my bad, I mistook it with another one. you are absolutely right

Answer (score 0):

There is a global replacement method [`replace`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions.fill)

```py
a = [
    ["#", "123"],
    ["ABC", "#"],
]

b = ["col_a", "col_b"]

df = spark.createDataFrame(a, b)

df.show()
+-----+-----+
|col_a|col_b|
+-----+-----+
|    #|  123|
|  ABC|    #|
+-----+-----+

df.replace("#", None).show()
+-----+-----+
|col_a|col_b|
+-----+-----+
| null|  123|
|  ABC| null|
+-----+-----+
```